# Most optimized way to update elements of a 2d array in Scala

Tags: scala

This piece of code updates all elements of a 2d array with some random value, is there any another simple and short code to solve this problem?

```
val terrainTypes = TerrainBlockType.values

(0 until width).foreach(i => {
    (0 until height).foreach(j => {
        val r = Random.nextInt(terrainTypes.length)
        terrainMap(i)(j) = terrainTypes(r)
    })
})
```

Comment: Are your looking for a more CPU-efficient way of doing the same thing, or for a shorter code that does the same thing?

Comment: @BehrangSaeedzadeh Both of them, but shorter is better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to update an array which already exists:

```
terrainMap.foreach(_.transform(_ =>
  terrainTypes(Random.nextInt(terrainTypes.length))
))
```

Answer (score 8):

Short code with new `Array` creation:

```
val terrainMap =
  Array.tabulate(width, height){ (_, _) =>
    terrainTypes(Random.nextInt(terrainTypes.length))
  }
```

If you need `for` loop optimization take a look at [`Scalaxy`](https://github.com/ochafik/Scalaxy/tree/master/Loops):

```
for {
  i <- 0 until width optimized;
  j <- 0 until height optimized
} {
  val r = Random.nextInt(terrainTypes.length)
  terrainMap(i)(j) = terrainTypes(r)
}
```

`Scalaxy` optimizes `for-comprehensions` using while loop.

Comment: Thanks, but my terrainMap is a value, I want to change each it's item, not the whole map

Comment: @Pooya: Then you have to make a choice between performance and   brevity. Brevity - [transform](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18042908/406435), performance - scalaxy. I'd prefer to use immutable data structures like `Vector`.